# syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: linux, bash

I created a script that helps administrators add and remove users from text file instead of doing it manually. I ran into this error and i'm having trouble solving it.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-55 ~]$ ./account-manager user add
./account-manager: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
./account-manager: line 21: `   then'
```

How could I fix this error?

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
action=$2

if [ -z "$file" ]
then
        echo " Please enter a file with your users"
        exit 0
fi

if [ -z "$action" ]
then
        echo " Please define an account to remove or deleete"
        exit 0
fi

for user in `cat $file`
do
        if[ "$action" == "add" ]
        then
                echo adding user: $user
                useradd $user -m -p password
        fi
        if[ "$action" == "remove" ]
        then
                echo removing user: $user
                userdel -r $user
        fi

done
```

Comment: `if[` is not the same thing as `if [` (note the space)

Comment: thank  mat it really helped  , post the answer and i'll accept ur one@Mat

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over the contents for a file in `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a space between `if` and `[` in lines 20 and 25. Your code should be like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
action=$2

if [ -z "$file" ]
then
        echo " Please enter a file with your users"
        exit 0
fi

if [ -z "$action" ]
then
        echo " Please define an account to remove or deleete"
        exit 0
fi

for user in `cat $file`
do
        if [ "$action" == "add" ]
        then
                echo adding user: $user
                useradd $user -m -p password
        fi
        if [ "$action" == "remove" ]
        then
                echo removing user: $user
                userdel -r $user
        fi

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to spacing around your `if` statements, make use of a tool such as http://www.shellcheck.net/ to understand where you might have made mistakes.